# Как правильно стереть символ в строке?

Tags: c

Трудности у меня возникли на этой задачке:

> Даны две строки длиной до 80 символов. Необходимо удалить заданный символ в каждой строке. Описать в виде отдельной функции удаление заданного символа в каждой строке.

Как сам попробовал решить:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <math.h>

int k, m;
char str[81], str2[81];

Eraser(char str[], char unsim, char str2[])
{
    for (int n = 0; str[n] != '\0'; n++)
        str2[n] = str[n];
    for (n = 0; str2[n] != '\0'; n++) {
        if (str2[n] == unsim) {
            str2[n] = str2[n++];
        }
    }
}

main()
{
    char unsim;
    printf(" Select intem to be removed n");
    scanf("%c", &unsim);
    printf("Enter, please a first line. n");
    scanf("%s", str);
    Eraser(str, unsim, str2);
    puts(str2);
    printf("Enter, please a second line. n");
    scanf("%s", str);
    Eraser(str, unsim, str2);
    puts(str2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут одной строки должно быть достаточно

```
void Easer (char str[], char unsim) {
 int i, j;
 for (i = j = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
  if (str[i] != unsim)
   str[j++] = str[i];
 str[j] = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Нужно разобрать строку по буквам, как вариант, хотя я не спец. по С, но вроде в scanf нужно указать не значение переменной, а её адрес. **(&)**
Выглядеть должно так

```
 scanf("%s", &str);
```

Программа то скомпилируется, но не будет работать корректно. А у вас адреса переменных не указаны.

Comment: @johniek_comp, если что, str и есть адрес начала строки, поэтому никаких & здесь лепить не нужно.

Comment: но scanf таки работает с указателями :)

Comment: @johniek_comp, в том, что scanf работает с указателями Вы **абсолютно правы**. 

В языках C,C++ для char str[], запись str будет именно указателем, т.е. адресом первого элемента массива str[]. 

Другими словами **str == &str[0]**.

*Учите матчасть, а то ведь до смерти заминусуют.*

Comment: я же написал что в С не очень...да же книг не читал, интуитивно надо было разобраться